# Can I access a remote registry key without administrative access on the remote computer?

Tags: c#, security, windows-7, .net-4.0, remote-registry

I am writing an application in C# (.NET 4) to run on Windows 7. The application needs to access the registry on a remote computer (also running Windows 7) and modify a specific key.

The application works fine if it impersonates a local administrator account on the target computer. But is it possible to perform this function without running as a local administrator? I know that I can set registry permissions on keys (for local access) - the part I am unsure about is how to make a remote connection to the registry key without administrator access.

Comment: Imagine the viruses you could write if this were possible.

Comment: @RaymondChen But I can make a remote connection to a file (via a file share) using an account with very limited access, without opening myself to arbitrary threats. Just a matter of setting the right configuration (in that case, the file and share permissons). I was looking for something similar for the registry - a way to grant access to the registry, or a portion of the registry, without granting access to the entire machine. I'm guessing from your comment that the answer is "no". :-(

Comment: If you can relax the security on the specific key to something less than administrator, then you can use the remote registry service to modify it without being administrator.

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, sorry I did not have the chance to try that out before posting the question. Sounds like it should work for me.